# Visual Studio hot key - switch Find context/location

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a hot key to toggle the search context/location in the "Find"/"Find in Files" commands (Ctr+F and Shift+Ctrl+F respectively )? I'm talking about the drop down that asks where to search for example Current Project, Current Document, Entire Solution etc.

"Find" is probably my *most used* feature since working with markup and CSS very often I can't just F12 to a selector definition or Shift+F12 to Find Usages, a regular text search is really the only option and I want to make this as efficient as possible.

Yes, I can tab to it but this takes 6-tabs and if I do it fast, often get the count wrong and prematurely execute bad searches; so it's not cutting it.

If there isn't a hotkey how can I set one? Ctrl + F3 would work well since F3 is "Find Next"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a command in Visual Studio that does what you are looking for.

If there is one, you can set the shortcut key in the Tools\Options menu (Environment\Keyboard).
[image: Keyboard mappings]

In the screenshot, I'm searching for all the VS command that contain "find".  Perhaps one of these is what you need.

Then move to the Press shortcut keys textbox and choose your desired key binding.

Comment: There are many "Find" commands, this screenshot only shows a few of them.

Comment: There seems to be no command for this. I looked through the list and nothing stands out. Thanks anyways. If there's a way to create your own please let me know

Comment: You can create your own VS customizations.  Look at the Visual Studio Extensions projects.